# How to get deferred.promise to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I am having a hard time with deferred.promise with jQuery. What is the proper way to do this?

JS

```
var init = function () {
    var getItems = getJson.getItemData;
     //Some other code that will use getItems
}

var getJson = function () {
  return{
    getItemData: function (){
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      $.get('itemData.json').success(function(response){
        deferred.resolve(response);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
};
```

This returns undefined. This is how I have similarly done it in angular, but have not done this with jQuery. Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: You dont need deffered, simply return the $.get

Comment: Is it a typo? do you want to do `getItems = getJson.getListData`? and `getItems` is a function, so you need to call it to get the promise?

Comment: Yes sorry. If I call it as a function it returns getJson.getItemData is not a function

Comment: See the answer below for why you still have the problem ... also `getListData` returns the wrong thing, it should return `deferred.promise()` not `deferred.promise` - overall this code is about 15.3 times more complex than it needs to be. Also, note, getItems will be a promise of a value, not a value - taking into consideration the rest of your code, I'm guessing that will be the next stumbling block

Comment: @JaromandaX, I'd +1 an answer like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's all your posted code boiled down to the minimum code required

```
var init = function () {
    $.get('itemData.json').then(function(getItems) {
        // here getItems is closer to what you want it to be
        //Some other code that will use getItems
    });
}
```

The rest was unnecessary cruft

Comment: So I try this way and get `Object {readyState: 1}` when I open that object there is `responseJSON` but `console.log(getItems.responseJSON)` gives undefined

Comment: read the comment I put in the code about what getItems will be (it's what it would be if your code was corrected too) ... I also predicted this in a comment on your question ... to get to the value of a promise, use its `.then`

Comment: see the edited answer - you need to figure out what `getItems` is at that point, I have no way of knowing